# When i installed my unity game (android), that always crashing

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine, crash, game-development

I'm many weeks trying to fix that error.

When i installed my unity game on Android,  that always crashing,
after that i found out why it's happening.

Game always crashing, because that don't create folder in **Android/Data**.

Please, who knows how to fix that error.

Comment: Cloud you give more info about your development environment?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that in unity under Edit>Preferences>ExternalTools you have the right version of SDK JDK and NDK installed

Comment: yes, i reinstall SDK and UnityEngine, but it's doesn't work :(

Comment: Go to Unity Players>Othersettings>and turn off Protect Graphics Memory.

Comment: Also under Player go to Minify and turn Debug and Release to "None"

Comment: Thats not working